# Codeblocks in Ubuntu or Windows. Any difference?

Tags: c++, windows, ubuntu, windows-7, codeblocks

I have been wondering for a while whether it makes any difference to the output or to anything else if I am using CODEBLOCKS on WINDOWS 7 or UBUNTU ??

I have been using C++ and a GNU GCC Compiler.

I am active on the online coding competitions and I wanted to know.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no real difference between the two platforms from an IDE standpoint, that's why it's still called the same program!  As for the compiled executables, obviously anything you compile in windows will not run on Linux and vice-versa.  That being said, as long as  you stick to functions contained within the standard libc library that the GCC compiler is linking against, your code will remain portable.  On the other-hand, if you start coding using Win32 functions, or using embedded assembler to perform platform-specific tasks, that code will not port cleanly to Linux ... but then again, that would be true no matter what environment you were using.

With C++, if you decide to utilize any of the newer C++11 features, you will need [to check the compatibility of your compiler](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport) with the feature you're attempting to utilize, and make sure anyone else attempting to compile and run your code also has access to either the same compiler version, or a compiler that also supports the desired functionality.